# Creating polygons in ArcGIS Pro based on Survey123 (possibly automated with Notebooks?)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-survey123, arcgis-notebook

I am by no means a professional when it comes to using GIS. I am taking an elective in college, doing a project of my own choosing in GIS.

This question relates to ArcGIS Pro, Survey123 and Notebooks.

*For this project, 3 other students and I created a survey based on a form which is used to categorize river systems in Germany. Based on certain factors in a river, the form helps you to ultimately calculate a value describing the overall quality of each segment of the river. These values can be used to implement colored bands along the river in a map. This lets you get an overview of the river's quality at a quick glance.

So far, we have collected this data for several river segments using the form for an example river. We have also recreated the form as a survey in Survey123, adding calculations in the XLS form of the survey to calculate the value described above (based on the value assigned to each answer given in the survey).*

**What we are now struggling with is a way to create the aforementioned color bands automatically in ArcGIS Pro based on the survey.** Our idea was this: when working with the survey - or form for that matter - you fill out which segment of the river you are working on. If possible, we wanted to use Notebooks to automatically create a polygon of a certain color - based on the value calculated inside Survey123 - along the segment of the river. (These 100 meter segments lie between two points and are set. You can find them in various databases of the state or country).

[image: Our example river in ArcGIS Pro. The river itself and the points segmenting it have already been added.]

Here is what these colored bands could look like (taken from ELWAS-Web)

[image: River segments in color]

**We're a little lost on how to implement this though.** Notebooks seems like a good way to automate tasks in GIS, however none of us have any experience with Python. We figured we could simply look for tutorials, as it is essentially only one task. However it  has proven difficult to effectively find these. There is no shortage of tutorials and help provided online, but since this seems to be a task that overlaps within ArcGIS, Survey123 and Notebooks, we haven't quite found something that solves the problem.

Comment: Hello @Patrick, the second screenshot that you have shared is the desired output? If yes, are the colored features polygons? And it seems to me like generating buffered regions along the line and symbolizing it as per the required structure.

Comment: Hello Yogi,

the second picture is how it will hopefully look, yes. Each river segment can basically be divided into 3/5/7 areas along each segment, depending on your needs (we'll most likely try for 5). The buffer command looks like it would really helpful for that! Although we're still stuck at the stage where we're trying to create the polygons according to the value that is calculated based on the Survey123